# Is there a way to disable caching for specific Rails tests or code blocks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, testing, ruby-on-rails-5

When testing Rails code I often need to clear the cache behind conditions because the changes happen in less than a second, and the cache key uses second-precision timestamps (or use something like Timecop to skew the timestamps).

I know about using the `null_store` to disable caching across all tests, but I want to be able to test *with* caching as well.  Is there a way to disable caching for specific tests or blocks of code?

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: This answer appears to address this question, at least for rspec: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31929514/rails-rspec-toggle-cache-for-a-single-test

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `cache_store` on the fly from your test script. For a particular test you can set `cache_store` to `null_store` using `Rails.configuration.cache_store = :null_store`.

Then you can revert `cache_store` to whatever your previous store was, for instance, `Rails.configuration.cache_store = :memory_store`.

Comment: Thanks - it doesn't seem to work, at least within a single method.  Reading http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Cache/Strategy/LocalCache.html it says caching still happens within the block.  I even tried setting the cache store to nil and didn't get any results.